# Issue with receiving notifications when app is in background

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase FCM service for my android app. Facing the listed down issues in it.

1. Sometimes when app receives notifications it doesn't sound. Below is the code snippet.

```
private fun createNotificationChannel(
    context: Context, id: String, name: String, description: String,
    path: Uri?, dnd: Boolean, importance: Int,
    notificationManager: NotificationManager
) {


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val existingChannel =
            notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id)

        if (existingChannel != null) {
            notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id)
        }
        val mAudioManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
            mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM),
            0
        )

        val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)

        channel.description = description
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.setShowBadge(true)
        channel.describeContents()
        channel.setBypassDnd(dnd)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        channel.lightColor = R.color.red
        channel.enableVibration(true)

        if (id == CHANNEL_ID_NORMAL_PRIORITY) {
            if (!SharedPrefUtils.getSharedPrefIsAppInForeground(context)) {
                channel.setSound(
                    path,
                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .build()
                )
            }
        } else if (id == CHANNEL_ID_HIGH_PRIORITY) {

            channel.setSound(
                path,
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build()
            )
        }

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

2. If App is not running for long time then the method onMessageReceived() of firebase messaging service is not getting called. In this case, when the app comes to the foreground, I am receiving notifications.
3. In push notification, I am sending only data payload because when the app is in background (either running or closed) and receives notification, if we use notification payload it won't set large icon to the banner. Below is code snippet for Push Notification.

```
AndroidConfig androidConfig = AndroidConfig.builder()
        .setTtl(3600 * 1000)
        .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
        //.setNotification(androidNotification)
        .putData("title", title)
        .putData("body", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(content))
        .putData("icon", icon)
        .putData("sound", soundData)
        .putData("channelid", channelId)
        .build();

Message msg = Message.builder()
        .setAndroidConfig(androidConfig)
        .setToken(token)
        .build();

String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(msg);
```

Comment: _"If App is not running for long time then the method onMessageReceived() of firebase messaging service is not getting called"_ That will depend on the type of messages that you send to your app (notification message or data message). For notification messages, `onMessageReceived` is only called if your app is in the foreground. Otherwise the the message will be delivered to the system notification tray.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using data messages only.

Comment: I am facing point 2 on the Vivo device ...

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Micheal pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833325/issue-with-receiving-notifications-when-app-is-in-background#comment111113040_62833325), this is (unfortunately) the expected behavior of the FCM when using the `notification` field.

Read more in the [`Handling messages` section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). And the important bit:

[image: handling messages summary]

---

*The usual fix for such scenarios is to change the way FCMs are structured:*

**Do not use `notification` field** (leave it completely unused), **but use the `data` field and build your local push notifications based on that.**

Comment: Hi @Bartek Lipinski, I am using only data messages. But when the app is killed. The app doesn't receive notifications.

Comment: @DeepashreeMulay maybe you have something (even if not used directly by You) in the `notification` field. If it's present (even if you're not using it) You will not have `onMessageReceived` when your app is killed.